# How to perform Drag and Drop of Item in a List View by Long Press of items

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` in which I have an image as a list of items. Now I want to perform drag and drop of an item in the list view. So for that, I created a class "DragNDropListView" which extends `ListView`, and override the onTouch() method of the list view inside this class and perform drag and drop operation and it works fine.

But my requirement is to do this drag and drop of item on long press of the image which are present in my list view. So how that can be done. Should I do the same thing as I have done in the `onTouch()` method of the list view or should I have to modify this method.

Please help me to sort this out.

**My code onTouch Method**

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) 
{
    final int action = ev.getAction();
    final int x = (int) ev.getX();
    final int y = (int) ev.getY();  
    
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
    {
        mDragMode = true;
    }

    if (!mDragMode) 
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);

    switch (action) 
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        mStartPosition = pointToPosition(x,y);
        if (mStartPosition != INVALID_POSITION) 
        {
            int mItemPosition = mStartPosition - getFirstVisiblePosition();
            mDragPointOffset = y - getChildAt(mItemPosition).getTop();
            mDragPointOffset -= ((int)ev.getRawY()) - y;
            startDrag(mItemPosition,y);
            drag(0,y);// replace 0 with x if desired
        }   
        break;
        
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        {
            drag(0,y);// replace 0 with x if desired
        }
        break;
        
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:             
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        
        default:
        mDragMode = false;
        mEndPosition = pointToPosition(x,y);
        stopDrag(mStartPosition - getFirstVisiblePosition());
        if (mDropListener != null && mStartPosition != INVALID_POSITION && mEndPosition != INVALID_POSITION) 
             mDropListener.onDrop(mStartPosition, mEndPosition);
        break;
    }
    return true;
}   

// move the drag view
private void drag(int x, int y) 
{
    if (mDragView != null) 
    {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) mDragView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.x = x;
        layoutParams.y = y - mDragPointOffset;
        WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mDragView, layoutParams);

        if (mDragListener != null)
            mDragListener.onDrag(x, y, null);// change null to "this" when ready to use
    }
}

// enable the drag view for dragging
private void startDrag(int itemIndex, int y) 
{
    stopDrag(itemIndex);

    View item = getChildAt(itemIndex);
    if (item == null) return;
    item.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    if (mDragListener != null)
        mDragListener.onStartDrag(item);
    
    // Create a copy of the drawing cache so that it does not get recycled
    // by the framework when the list tries to clean up memory
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(item.getDrawingCache());
    
    WindowManager.LayoutParams mWindowParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    mWindowParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    mWindowParams.x = 0;
    mWindowParams.y = y - mDragPointOffset;

    mWindowParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    mWindowParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    mWindowParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS;
    mWindowParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    mWindowParams.windowAnimations = 0;
    
    Context context = getContext();
    ImageView v = new ImageView(context);
    v.setImageBitmap(bitmap);      

    WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    mWindowManager.addView(v, mWindowParams);
    mDragView = v;
}

// destroy drag view
private void stopDrag(int itemIndex) 
{
    if (mDragView != null) {
        if (mDragListener != null)
            mDragListener.onStopDrag(getChildAt(itemIndex));
        mDragView.setVisibility(GONE);
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.removeView(mDragView);
        mDragView.setImageDrawable(null);
        mDragView = null;
    }
}
```

**Used of Listener**

```
    ListView listView = getListView();

    if (listView instanceof DragNDropListView) 
    {
        ((DragNDropListView) listView).setDropListener(mDropListener);
        ((DragNDropListView) listView).setRemoveListener(mRemoveListener);
        ((DragNDropListView) listView).setDragListener(mDragListener);
    }

private DropListener mDropListener = new DropListener() 
{
    public void onDrop(int from, int to) 
    {
        ListAdapter adapter = getListAdapter();
        if (adapter instanceof ListViewAdapter) 
        {
            ((ListViewAdapter)adapter).onDrop(from, to);
            getListView().invalidateViews();
        }
    }
};

private RemoveListener mRemoveListener = new RemoveListener() 
{
    public void onRemove(int which) 
    {
        ListAdapter adapter = getListAdapter();
        if (adapter instanceof ListViewAdapter) {
            ((ListViewAdapter)adapter).onRemove(which);
            getListView().invalidateViews();
        }
    }
};


private DragListener mDragListener = new DragListener() 
{
    public void onDrag(int x, int y, ListView listView)
    {
    }

    public void onStartDrag(View itemView) 
    {
        itemView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        if (iv != null) iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void onStopDrag(View itemView) 
    {
        itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        if (iv != null) iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can simply use some listener to your listview -

```
public interface DropListener {

/**
 * Called when an item is to be dropped.
 * @param from - index item started at.
 * @param to - index to place item at.
 */
    void onDrop(int from, int to);
}
```

Try to see this [Example.](http://www.ziddu.com/download/17692566/DragNDrop.zip.html)

Comment: yeh i had used listener..u plz check the code and let me help to perform this on long press of imageview..and m working using that example only as u have gave me the link.....

Comment: @Anshuman I've not yet tried. Customize the classes by yourself with your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return touchHandler(event);
}

private boolean touchHandler(final MotionEvent event) {
    final int action = event.getAction();
    final int x = (int) event.getX();
    final int y = (int) event.getY();
    if (prevY < 0) {
        prevY = y;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Motion event " + event.getAction());
    int flatPosition = pointToPosition(x, y);
    dragRatio = getHeight() / screenHeight;
    long packagedPosition = getExpandableListPosition(flatPosition);

    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
            && getPackedPositionType(packagedPosition) == 1) {
        if (dragOnLongPress) {
            if (pressedItem) {
                mDragMode = true;
                pressedItem = false;
            } else {
                pressedItem = true;
                Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // y coordinate is changing for no reason ??
                        event.setLocation(x, y);
                        touchHandler(event);
                    }
                };
                handler.postDelayed(r, 200);
                return true;
            }
        } else if (x < dragOffset) {
            mDragMode = true;
        }
    }

    if (!mDragMode) {
        /** when user action on other areas */
        if ((pressedItem && Math.abs(prevY - y) > 30)
                || event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            pressedItem = false;
            handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        mStartFlatPosition = flatPosition;
        mStartPosition[0] = getPackedPositionGroup(packagedPosition);
        mStartPosition[1] = getPackedPositionChild(packagedPosition);
        if (packagedPosition != PACKED_POSITION_VALUE_NULL) {

            int mItemPosition = flatPosition - getFirstVisiblePosition();
            mDragPointOffset = y - getChildAt(mItemPosition).getTop();
            mDragPointOffset -= ((int) event.getRawY()) - y;
            startDrag(mItemPosition, y);
            if (listeners != null) {
                listeners.onPick(mStartPosition);
            }
            drag(x, y);
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        int speed = (int) ((y - prevY) * dragRatio);
        if (getLastVisiblePosition() < getCount() && speed > 0) {
            smoothScrollBy(speed, 1);
        }
        if (getFirstVisiblePosition() > 0 && speed < 0) {
            smoothScrollBy(speed, 1);
        }
        drag(x, y);// replace 0 with x if desired
        if (listeners != null) {
            listeners.onDrag(x, y);
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    default:

        mDragMode = false;
        if (getPackedPositionType(packagedPosition) == 0) {
            mEndPosition[0] = getPackedPositionGroup(packagedPosition);
            mEndPosition[1] = 0;
        } else {
            mEndPosition[0] = getPackedPositionGroup(packagedPosition);
            mEndPosition[1] = getPackedPositionChild(packagedPosition);
        }

        stopDrag(mStartFlatPosition);
        if (packagedPosition != PACKED_POSITION_VALUE_NULL) {
            if (adapter != null) {
                adapter.onDrop(mStartPosition, mEndPosition);
            }
            if (listeners != null) {
                listeners.onDrop(mStartPosition, mEndPosition);
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    prevY = y;
    return true;
}
```

Check the drag and drop expandable listview with long press [here](https://github.com/sreekumarsh/android/tree/master/Drag%20N%20Drop) you can modify this and implement this to a listview