# Drag and Drop List

Tags: android, listview

Will I be able to create a ListView which supports Drag and drop property and doesn't have any handler (which handles the drag property)?

Comment: [Try to see this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10736108/940096)

Comment: [Complete Example](http://ericharlow.blogspot.in/2010/10/experience-android-drag-and-drop-list.html)

Comment: I want to remove that imageview in the list item in the download...Help me How to do it...ie,I want to drag and drop the list item by clicking and dragging as well as Handle the touch in it...

Answer (score 2):

Here is our drag & drop list. It is a direct replacement for ListView and it's very easy to use. There are examples of how to use on its github page. It does have a handler, but you can set the entire listview row as a handler, then you will be able to drag it no matter where you touch.

https://github.com/terlici/DragNDropList